# How can I do request from subrequest?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT goods, price, category
FROM factory1
JOIN factory2
WHERE price IN ( SELECT price FROM factory2 WHERE date* ...)
```

*How can I do here in main  request with "date" from subrequest "factory2"?*

```
AND date* BETWEEN TO_DATE ( '2013/07/01','YYYY/MM/DD' ) AND TO_DATE ( '2013/07/07', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

Thank you for any help.

**UPDATED #1**

Sorry, maybe my example is not quite accurate. ***I need the information is entered in the subquery must be to introduced into the main query***, I do not know how to implement it.
I'll try to show what I want:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Orders
    WHERE snum IN
       ( SELECT snum 
         FROM Salespeople 
         WHERE odate = 10/03/1990 );
```

I need to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Orders
    WHERE snum IN
       ( SELECT snum 
         FROM Salespeople 
         WHERE odate = (X) )
    AND (X) = 10/03/1990;
```

Maybe it's need a `function` or `context`, but I have never worked with it before. 
Thanks.

**UPDATED #2**
Here is a part of my real task:

```
CREATE VIEW cash_deposit
(
    type,
    city_code,
    city_name,
    member_code,
    member_name,
    operation,
    amount,
    sum_operation,
    sum_amount,
    date,
    ...
)
AS
SELECT DISTINCT type, city_code, city_name, member_code, member_name, operation, amount, sum_operation, sum_amount, date, ...
FROM (SELECT type, city_code, city_name, member_code, member_name, operation, amount, sum_operation, sum_amount, date
      FROM (SELECT DISTINCT *mainPartOfAmount*, member_code, member_name, operation, date
            FROM database1.action1 T
            JOIN database1.action2 S ON S.key=T.key AND S.act=1
            JOIN database1.action3 E ON E.key=S.key AND E.act=1 AND *mainPartOfAmount* IN
                (SELECT DISTINCT *mainPartOfAmount*
                 FROM (SELECT *mainPartOfAmount*, *summ_amount*, date
                       FROM database1.action1 T
                       JOIN database1.action2 S ON S.key=T.key AND S.act=1
                       JOIN database1.action3 E ON E.key=S.key AND E.act=1
                       JOIN database1.action4 Q ON Q.key=T.key
                       JOIN database1.action5 Z ON Z.key=Q.key
                       WHERE T.*summ_amount* IN (SELECT *summ_amount* 
                                                 FROM (SELECT R.*summ_amount*, R.date 
                                                       FROM database1.action1 R)
                                                )
                       AND --condition #1
                       GROUP BY *mainPartOfAmount*, date)
                )
          JOIN database1.action4 Q ON Q.key=T.key
          JOIN database1.action5 Z ON Z.key=Q.key
          WHERE T.*summ_amount* IN (SELECT *summ_amount* 
                                    FROM (SELECT R.*summ_amount*, R.date 
                                          FROM database1.action1 R)
                                   )
          AND --condition #2
          GROUP BY *mainPartOfAmount*, date
         )
     )Block1
JOIN
SELECT ( .... )Block2
ON Block1.member_code = Block2.member_code
JOIN
SELECT ( .... )Block3
ON Block1.member_code = Block3.member_code
--here must be the information is entered for the subquery of R.date in Block1:
--WHERE R.date BETWEEN TO_DATE ( '2013/07/01','YYYY/MM/DD' ) AND TO_DATE ( '2013/07/07', 'YYYY/MM/DD') (for example)
ORDER BY type, member_code, sum_operation, date
```

That's why i tried to ask as short, as it possible :)

Comment: I don't understand your question. Try to tell us in English rather than in SQL what records you want to see. How are factory1 and factory2 related by the way, and from which of the two tables do goods, price and category come from?

Comment: It would help if you aliased your tables and explicitly denoted which fields come from which tables, eg., `select f.goods, p.price, f.category from factory1 f, factory2 p ...`

Comment: I need the information is entered in the subquery must be introduced into the main query. I've updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this is what you mean, but I think you are mixing `join` and `where` up.

Did you mean something like this? If not, please make clearer what you mean.

```
SELECT DISTINCT goods, price, category
FROM factory1 f1
JOIN factory2 f2
ON f1.price = f2.price
WHERE f2.date BETWEEN TO_DATE ( '2013/07/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD' ) AND TO_DATE ( '2013/07/07', 'YYYY/MM/DD')
```